# How to get the path for openFile in Haskell?

Tags: macos, haskell, path, functional-programming, program-entry-point

I have the following program which throws a runtime exception:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  handle <- openFile "palindrome.txt" ReadMode
  input  <- hGetContents handle
  hClose handle
```

It type checks, but whenever I try to run `main`, I'll get an error:

[image: Atom session on Mac OS X]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A little bit more information. Where do you execute your program, where is `file.txt`?

Comment: thanks for reply. i run a shell and open ghci mode there, on a mac. file.txt is in the same folder like the program itself

Comment: [edit] your question with additional information. Show your whole GHCi session and the relevant contents of your working directory, e.g. `ls -l *.txt`.

Comment: added screenshot. working directory is on the left, path there in second line of shell

Comment: Well, where do you execute GHCi? Probably in `/home/Mauritius/Uni/Vorlesungen/Haskell/`. Either way, __that's__ where GHCi will look for your file. You need to provide a complete path. By the way, this is the same for __all__ programming languages: if you use relative paths, you need to run the program at the right place.

Comment: ok thanks! i just started ghc from that directory and it worked all fine. but as i work on different files and i don't want to leave ghci all the time, is there a way of getting that path and adding it after openFile?

Comment: You mean like "ask the user for the path"? That would be `getLine` or similar. By the way `openFile path ReadMode >>= \handle -> hGetContents handle >>= \input -> hClose handle >> return input` is the same as `readFile path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current program uses a relative path. As such, the file must be in the same directory where you started GHCi. Given that your workspace is `$HOME/Desktop/Haskell`, it probably checks only for `$HOME/Desktop/Haskell/palindrome.txt`. If you want to use the `palindrome.txt` in $HOME/Desktop/Haskell/u03/3-1/`, you need to either use the absolute path in your code, or run GHCi in that directory.

Note that you can change the current directory in GHCi with `:cd`, so the following commands in GHCi should work:

```
Prelude> :cd /path/to/your/directory
Prelude> :l palindrom-a.hs
*Main> :main
```

Comment: okay, working fine now. did't know that i can use :cd in ghci.

Comment: @Mauritius: Check `:?` or `:help` for a full list of all commands.